# Manipulate SectionList from API

Tags: react-native

I am fetching and manipulating my sectionList by api data. My api events list looks like this.

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "event_id": 76,
            "core_symptom": "tiredness",
            "note": "Tiredness after short walk",
            "created_at": "2020-06-29T03:09:24.000Z",
            "audio_url": "https://medbeat.beat.se",
            "audio_title": "2020-02-20 11:57:22",
            "monitor_id": 2
        },     
        {
            "event_id": 68,
            "core_symptom": "headpain",
            "note": "Head pain test entry from mobile phone",
            "created_at": "2020-06-24T03:35:54.000Z",
            "audio_url": "https://medbeat.beat.se",
            "audio_title": "2020-02-20 11:57:22",
            "monitor_id": 2
        },
    ]
}
```

please help me how can I use "created_at" as section header and "core_symptom" as list items.

Answer (score 1):

Expected data structure for SectionList is an array of "sections" (you can check more [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist#section)). What I usually do when working with them is using some third party library like lodash, i.e. the [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) function.

```
import { groupBy, map } from 'lodash'

const dictionary = groupBy(yourEventAPIArray, e => e.created_at;

const sections = map(dictionary, (data, key) => {
   day: key,
   data
});
```

Now you have a proper structure for sections props of SectionList, you just need to pass it and work with `renderItem` and `renderSectionHeader`.

```
<SectionList sections={sections} 
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Text>{item.core_symptom}</Text>}  
  renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => <Text>{section.day}</Text>}
/>
```

As you can see, basically sections is just an array with a prop for key (you section header) and a data which is the array of items for that sections.

Hope it'll help :)

Comment: thank for you help. here is my code and in the bottom I also have pasted api response. can you please help me how exactly do that.

Comment: Ohhh sorry. 
https://snack.expo.io/@anisahmad/rude-cookies

Comment: This code display list items but its not display sections header. I want to sort my items according to data of creation. same as we see in our whatsapp chat history , today, yesterday May, April  and so on...

Comment: @AneesAhmad Also, if you want you can sort your array per "day" value (using lodash) to obtain a timeline effect.

Comment: I did the same but getting these errors.

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.length')

This error is located at:
    in VirtualizedSectionList (at SectionList.js:301)
    in SectionList (at EventListScreen.js:92)
    in RCTView (at EventListScreen.js:85)

Comment: As I console the data. it logs like this..

Array [
  Array [
    Object {
      "audio_title": "2020-02-20 11:57:22",
      "audio_url": "https://medbeat.beat.se",
      "core_symptom": "dizliness",
      "created_at": "2020-06-29T04:58:20.000Z",
      "event_id": 79,
      "monitor_id": 2,
      "note": "I felt dizzy while taking a shower",
    },
  ],
  Array [
    Object {
      "audio_title": "2020-02-20 11:57:22",
      "audio_url": "https://medbeat.beat.se",
      "core_symptom": "tiredness",
      "created_at": "2020-06-29T03:09

Comment: If you can provide the Snack working with the imports, I'd like to help. Btw I think your problem is only related to mapping correctly the data source. You just need to create an array with a key property (which I guess it'd be your date) and a data prop which is the array of event related to that date and that's it

Comment: Here is snack, I tried my best but did not succeeded. 
https://snack.expo.io/@anisahmad/event-list

Comment: @AneesAhmad I've written an example without styling and effective httprequest, but I think you can paste the formatting part here. I've copy pasted the code that I linked in the answer above. https://snack.expo.io/VQhaUOWPt If you can accept the answer it'd be great :)

Comment: Just manipulate your date with plain JS or moment or whatever you want. `groupBy(events, (e) => new Date(e.created_at).toLocaleDateString()),`

Comment: Great  and thanks, but, I want a signal header for each day. see now we have like this 

2020-07-01T03:34:45.000Z
stomach pain
2020-07-01T03:11:59.000Z
headpain
2020-07-01T02:47:49.000Z
fever 

these events are created in same day eg 1st july and I want these like this

2020-07-01 T03:34:45.000Z
stomach pain
headpain
fever

and next day all of created events should be under that heading of that date on which they are created

Comment: Updated the snack, just copied the code of the last comment in the snack. https://snack.expo.io/B5ReeTaTk

Comment: Thank you so much, its up and running now.

Comment: one more thing. I am fetching this data from api. first its show a blank screen. its show me data when I remove and rewrite any data variable. I think there should be async await. how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It's another issue, it's related on how you can handle http request properly. I suggest you to mark this one as done and opening a new question on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: It was my second question on stack overflow. I don’t know about accepting the answer. is there anything I need to do if I got a solution?

Comment: Can you please help me to resolve this issues as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62781375/sectionlist-is-not-displaying-list-data

Comment: @AneesAhmad on the main answer, you'd mark it as "accepted" (green tick). I'm gonna check your other question later!